# Can we use OneLogin/Okta/Auth0 as Proxy SP between Google IdP and application

Tags: saml-2.0, auth0, okta, onelogin

We have an application for which we would like to enable users to login into our application with their own Identity Providers like Google, ADFS etc with SAML 2.0 as protocol.

In this context our application will be SP and Identity Providers will be Google, ADFS.

But currently we don't have SAML implementation at our application, so we would like to use some platform like OneLogin/Okta/Auth0 as middle proxy between our application and IdP so that SAML related handling can be done at OneLogin/Okta/Auth0 and we need to get callback to our application with user details after success login.

Is this possible with any SASS based SAML providers? and how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes - connect to Auth0 / Okta via OpenID Connect and then connect the IDP to other IDP via SAML.

So in this context, Auth0 / Okta is a SAML SP.

Have a look [here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/selecting-the-connection-for-multiple-logins).